# Will draining a pond more quickly reduce groundwater level underneath?

Tags: plumbing, drainage, landscaping

There's a pond that develops in my backyard slightly up slope where it's flat. I have a drain that persistently drains this but obviously it's not enough since the pool still exists during storms.

Compounding this, there's another issue regarding the ground water being a bit high. I'm curious if the persistent surface water in the pond is contributing to the groundwater buildup. I live significantly above sea level, so the groundwater is likely localized pockets.

The pond probably takes a week or two to fully drain with the drain hose(5in diameter at half full almost the whole time). The pond is about 5 ft above uphill from my house. The relative groundwater at my house is about 4ft deep during rainy season. There are other sources of groundwater since everyone uses septic, but most of the water is likely accumulation from rainwater that collects in the depression in this spot.

If I flush out the pond more quickly in the yard, can I make a dent in the groundwater buildup?

Comment: The answer depends on factors which we don't have, such as relative levels of the pond and groundwater, other sources of groundwater, underground drainage rates, etc. There's no way anyone here can say anything other than "maybe".

Comment: You can only mitigate storms so much, you can't defeat nature, especially water.  If its drains in a few hours after the storm, then it is a good result.

Comment: thats the problem, it doesnt drain in a few hours. probably takes a week or two to fully drain. 
The pond is about 5 ft above uphill from my house. The relative groundwater at my house is about 4ft deep during rainy season. There are other sources of groundwater since everyone uses septic, but most of the water is likely accumulation from rainwater that collects in the depression in this spot.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that holds water will affect the ground water level near it, since water will flow into the ground unless it's non-permeable ground.

Now, a 3 meter/10 foot wide pond that lasts a day will have a minimal effect.  A 30 m/100 ft pond is another story entirely.  Also, your local water doesn't care about sea level, it's all about what is happening right there. I had terrible water problems at 1200 ft elevation.

Comment: I have a friend who lived near the top of a serious hill and still got their basement flooded by groundwater that fell on nearby fields, hit the rock of the hill, and found their property one of the easiest ways down. Groundwater can be _very_ local.

Comment: its maybe a 10foot wide pond after several days of storms, this is with constant drainage from my pipe. There was a huge storm that lasted a week which pushed the pond to spill over and flow down the hill(theres a raised ground that traps the pond normally). Typically from my observation the pond is still being drained even a week after rain.

Comment: @mugetsu, yes you  should probably get it to drain faster